# render Model's properties dynamically - Angular

Tags: angular, loops, dynamic, ngfor

I have a model comes from backend with many properties, example:

```
item:{
Name,
Quantity,
Price,
...
}
```

and I'm rendering that model's properties in html like:

```
<p>{{item.Name}}</p>
<p>{{item.Quantity}}</p>
```

but if a new property added to the model I have to add it to the code.
I need a way to iterate the model's properties without write them in a hardcode way

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<p *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(item)">
{{ item[key] }}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through object's properties using Object.entries() method

```
Object.entries(item)
```

Above method will return list of properties. Use that with ngFor in your html

Answer (score -1):

You can use *ngfor directive in your HTML template

ngFor is a built-in directive in angular. it's easy to iterate over objects, arrays, etc using ngFor. You can think of ngFor is the same as for loop or foreach loop in JS.

**Example:**

```
<p *ngFor="let eachItem of item;>
{{ eachItem }}
</p>
```

**Update**

You can use angular builin KeyValuePipe that transform objects and maps into array of key value pairs. [Check Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

I implemented a small example check [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-znkqf4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: excuse me but my question is not how can I iterate from an array, my answer is how can I iterate from an model properties

Comment: @James.mikael you can use builtin keyValuePipe. I update my answer.